# Add Demographics one by one in Hierarchial Regression

Tags: regression, probability, multiple-regression, linear-model, multilevel-analysis

I'm doing a psychological study where I am trying to find if different demographics (Gender, Age, Political Affiliation, Ethnicity, and Education level) have an effect on their susceptibility to the framing effect (measured on a 1-6 Likert scale). I will be doing this analysis three times, once for each question that I asked pertaining to framing.

I am currently planning to do a Hierarchical Regression of multiple steps, where the first step is no demographics, then each step after that I add one demographic to determine its effects on the model. However, in many pieces of literature, I found that studies often put all the demographics in the first step, and test other predictors in the other steps. However, in my case, I am trying to test if each of the demographics have an effect on the framing effect.

My questions are:

1. Would adding each demographic individually for each step be a valid use case of a Hierarchical Regression?
2. Can I make the conclusion that, for example, "Gender was found to have an effect on the participant's susceptibility to the framing effect".
3. I understand that hierarchical regression is used for models, but am I able to use it to find out which Gender is more susceptible to the framing effect with statistical significance (higher number on the Likert Scale)?

Comment: 1) how many subjects do ya got? (you'll find the folks around here not too receptive to stepwise regression, but I understand that you may not be in a position to change the practice of your field). 2) No, this analysis would not be sufficient to claim an effect, only a relationship 3) you will want to look at the p-values associated with the gender regression coefficient to determine this